# How do you use VBA in excel to locate specific locations and copy the data from that sheet into another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

In the one sheet: "SHEET A", I have 6463 rows, which has the location values (i.e., 123456) in column A2 to A6463 and other data from column B2 to P6463.

In the second sheet: "SHEET B", I have a three letter code (i.e., ABC) specifying what location values go with it from A2 to Z26. The acronyms are in the header column (A1 to Z1).

For example, the acronym: "ABC" is in A1. 
It has 2 locations (A2: "123456", A3: "654321"). 
Each acronym has at least 1 location and is 6 characters long (mat have a letter at the beginning). 
Each acronym can have up to 25 locations.

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the locations for "ABC" in "SHEET A" and copying the data from column A to P into another sheet labeled: "ABC".

In the end, there should be 26 new sheets renamed as the acronym with their specified location(s) and the relevant data from "SHEET A" in the new sheet..

Does that make sense? Can someone help me with this problem?

```
Sub Macro5()
    Cells.Find(What:="123456", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "ABC"
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: No, this doesn't make sense. How is "ABC" logically linked to Sheet A?  You indicate only that Sheet A contains the location values.  And that Sheet B contains the acronyms.  Are the acronmys somewhere on Sheet A so that you could do a lookup function?  If not, you need to provide more detail about the relationship between these location values and the acronyms.

Comment: The acronyms have location values from "SHEET A" in "SHEET B".

For example: In "SHEET A" there are two columns: LOCATION #: (123456) and LOCATION NAME (USA CALIFORNIA - ABCX

In "SHEET B" there is are acronyms such as "ABC" and the location codes below. ABC directly correlates with "123456". Thus, I would assume you could find them in "SHEET A"

Comment: are the locations in Sheet A like "123456" or are they like "(123456)" as you indicate in your last comment.  Do you understand why this difference *matters*?  Also, **what have you tried so far**?  You're asking for a VBA solution, but so far have not demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem on your own. I think this can be done using the `Index` function to return the relative row # from Sheet A, then you can use that row and the columns A to P to define a `Range` object, the values from which can easily be copied and pasted to a new worksheet.

Comment: The locations in Sheet A are 123456 no quotes or parenthesis. Sorry for the confusion. I have tried to record the macro, since that's the only way I know how. I don't necessarily understand VBA that well. What I did was: record it --> ctrl F for 123456 --> ctrl A to select all of the location values --> select all the other data that pertains to 123456 from B2 to P22 --> Copy --> Add a new sheet --> renamed it ABC --> pasted the data into that sheet. I don't think that's a good way of doing it. So, I have searched online, but have been unsuccessful. This is my last resort.

Comment: Why don't you include the code generated by the macro recorder?  [This is expected of you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You're right, that is not a terribly efficient way of doing it, but it is usually easier for someone to assist you if you're not asking them to reinvent the wheel.  Also, while there are more sophisticated ways of acheiving the desired results, if we work with "your" existing code, it is more likely that you will be able to understand it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so as I mentioned in the comments, using `Find` is maybe not the most efficient way of doing this but it should work, and will probably be easiest to explain.

What we are going to do is declare some *variables* that we can use to represent your data: what we're searching for, where we're searching for it, the several worksheets you're using, etc.

Then we will *loop* over each *row* (location ID) beneath each acronmym on Sheet B.

This is entirely untested:

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim shtA as Worksheet   'variable represents Sheet A
    Dim shtB as Worksheet   'variable represents Sheet B
    Dim shtNew as Worksheet 'variable to hold the "new" sheet for each acronym
    Dim acronyms as Range 'range to define the list of acronyms
    Dim cl as Range     'cell iterator for each acronmym
    Dim r as Integer    'iterator, counts the number of locatiosn in each acronym
    Dim valueToFind As String 'holds the location that we're trying to Find
    Dim foundRange as Range   'the result of the .Find() method

    '## Assign our worksheets variables
    Set shtA = Worksheets("Sheet A")
    Set shtB = Worksheets("Sheet B")

    '## Assign the list of acronmys in Sheet B
    Set acronyms = shtB.Range("A1:Z1")  

    '## Begin our loop over each acronym:
    For each cl in acronyms.Cells
        '## Add a new sheet for each acronym:
        Set shtNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        shtNew.Name = cl.Value

        r = 1 'start each acronym at "1"

        '## Loop over each row, which contain the location IDs
        '   assumes that there is no additional data below the location IDs
        '   this terminates at the first empty cell in each column
        Do While Not cl.Offset(r).Value = ""

            '## Define the value we're looking for:
            valueToFind = cl.Offset(r).Value

            'Search in "SHEET A", Column A
            With shtA.Range("A:A")
                '## Assign the result of the Find method to a range variable:
                Set foundRange = .Find(What:=valueToFind, _
                                       After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                       MatchCase:=False, _
                                       SearchFormat:=False)

            End With

            '## Make sure the value was found:
            If foundRange Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox valueToFind & " not found!"
            Else:
                '## Resize the foundRange to include columns A:P
                Set foundRange = foundRange.Resize(1, 16)

                '## Copy & paste to the new worksheet for this acronym
                foundRange.Copy Destination:=shtNew.Cells(r,1)
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried a test, and there was an error when adding a new sheet. --- 'Set shtNew = Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)' ---. I appreciate your help. I think this is plausible.

Comment: That line should say: `Set shtNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))`.  I revised my answer. Let me know if it gives you trouble on any other line(s).

Comment: Gotcha. Now I receive a compile error: "For without Next". So I'm thinking when you have that For Each statement, there should be a Next statement somewhere.

Comment: Yes, there should be `Next` :) put it in the line *after* `Loop`.

Comment: Okay. It does work. However, I got one row for the location I wanted. Is there any chance I get all of them for that acronym? Is there something I can change in the code? And am I able to get the rest of the acronyms and their locations as well?

Comment: Yes, insert a line before `End If` and put this: `r = r + 1`.

Comment: That works! Now I'm having an issue where one of the locations is not found in Sheet B, which I can probably just delete manually, but can't you do a resume on error statement or something like that to prevent it from constantly sending a pop-up saying it can't be found?

Comment: Also, I'm realizing that it's just inputting one row of each location. There are multiple rows of just one location. For example, the location: 123456 is only showing up one time, where it should be showing up 39 more times because there is more data and information associated with that location.

Comment: If you don't want the message box, then just delete that line. It's not an "error", it's just an alert to inform you that some value is not found.  If you have to account for multiple instance of a location ID (I did not assume this in my code), then I would suggest using the `AutoFilter` method instead of `.Find` in that case. There are examples here on SO of how to do that. Give it a shot and if you get stuck, ask another Q and you are likely to get some more help :)